# OBD2 for car customization

Tags: obd-ii, suzuki, custom, swift

i was wondering if it could be possible use CAN protocol to automate some of my car (Suzuki Swift 2016 1.3 DDiS) processes, such as close windows when door get locked. I found lot of applications/software that can do that but just with other manifacturers' cars. Is there a specific list of command somewhere on the internet for my car which i can use?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

On most vehicles, you can code behavioral changes through the OBD2 port. That said, all of that information is vendor and vehicle specific and very hard to find.